# convert a String array to a 2d array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I have a String array like this

```
3
1 5 5
2 -2 -3
15 -100 20
```

how can i convert this to a 2d array

```
1 5 5
2 -2 -3
15 -100 20
```

3 is the size of 2d

```
public static class convert(String[] lines){
    int n = Integer.parseInt(lines[0]);             
    int[][] matrix = new int[n][n];
    for (int j = 1; j < n; j++) {
        String[] currentLine = lines[j].split(" ");
        for (int i = 0; i < currentLine.length; i++) {
            matrix[j][i] = Integer.parseInt(currentLine[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Fix the typo `j = 1` ---> `j = 0`, other than that it's all good.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, he would actually have to then change "lines[j].split(" ");" line to "String[] currentLine = lines[j+1].split(" ");" which would be two changes, or he could just leave j alone and change the matrix assignment, please see my answer for more detail!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sin,

You have a couple of [`Off-by-one errors`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error).

Try this:

```
int n = Integer.parseInt(lines[0]); 
int[][] matrix = new int[n][n];
for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
                String[] currentLine = lines[j].split(" ");
                for (int i = 0; i < currentLine.length; i++) {
                    matrix[j-1][i] = Integer.parseInt(currentLine[i]);
                }
}
```

Please let me know if you have any questions!

Answer (score 1):

Since arrays are 0-indexed in Java, you should change your loop initialization variable `j` to start at 0.

Change:

```
for (int j = 1; j < n; j++) {
```

to

```
for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
```

Also, it seems you want a method to do the conversion, not a `class` so you should remove this from your method signature and put `void` since you aren't returning anything from the method.

Change:

```
public static class convert(String[] lines)
```

To:

```
public static void convert(String[] lines)
```

Also, you should use a different variable to iterate through the string array to make things more cleaner. Since you are trying to use `j`, you can do that to. Instead of initializing `j` to 1, you initialize it to 0 as I've said and use `j+1` as the index for accessing the `lines` array.

Here is how your code could look like:

```
public static void convert(String[] lines)
    int n = Integer.parseInt(lines[0]);             
    int[][] matrix = new int[n][n];
    for (int j = 0, k = 1; j < n; j++) {
        String[] currentLine = lines[j + 1].split(" ");
        for (int i = 0; i < currentLine.length; i++) {
            matrix[j][i] = Integer.parseInt(currentLine[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks so much. it worked. the problem is "String[] currentLine = lines[j + 1].split(" ");"